# Clothing Split at Seams - Cannot Rig

Tags: rigging

Hello everyone and thank you in advance,

I know I'll feel dumb when the answer is presented as obvious by one of you, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use clothing based assets from Sketchfab in my own scenes.

The specific problem I am having is they come into my scene fine, but nearly every mesh I download has seams( I think we can call it that?). Basically the mesh is split where stitching would exist. Which makes sense if they marked seams there for UVs

My main problem is, I cannot seem to figure out how to rig these articles of clothing as once I apply a rig to them, or try to data transfer it to my existing character, it doesn't work as like I said the mesh is split at the seams and when I rotate a bone the sleeve separates for example from the main body of the jacket for example

This is the exact article of clothing I am trying to rig

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/cloth-jacket-f880b45cde9f41cf9b4afbfe25ce9887

I very much appreciate some advice as I've spent hours on this... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would merge the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* in *Edit* mode), make it fit the character in the rest pose, then transfer the weights from the body.

In *Object* mode select the jacket and the shirt, then the body last (=active object) and choose menu entry *Object > Link/Transfer Data > Transfer Mesh Data*, then *Vertex Group*. Use the options *All Layers, By Name* in the popup.

[image: jacket]

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I was trying to do this but oddly enough I couldn’t see overlapping vertices at the seams in edit mode. Is there a trick to quickly do that?

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to actually see duplicated vertices. The *Merge by Distance* operation only shows the number of merged vertices in the status bar. I forget to mention that this only works for the selected vertices. You can either select the areas around the seams or just the whole mesh to get them all. My experience was that duplicated vertices cause a lot of trouble when you do the weight paint.